# setSrc() function not allowed on image component ExtJS 4.2

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.2

I have this fieldset with image component inside:

```
    {
        xtype : 'fieldset',
        title : 'Picture',
        width : 170,
        items : [{
            xtype : 'image',
            itemId : 'uploadImage',
            height : 150,
            width : 150,
            src : ''
        }]
    }
```

The field set is inside a window called with alias: widget.profile, so I am using this line to access my image component

```
Ext.ComponentQuery.query('profile [itemId=uploadImage]');
```

Ok it gives me the image component and there is function setSrc() but I cannot use it, as if there is some permission on it. What do I do wrong, or is there a bug in extjs 4.2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code

```
Ext.ComponentQuery.query('profile [itemId=uploadImage]');
```

returns array of matched components not single component. So if you have in your application only one component which match the query you can get it by:

```
var img = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('profile [itemId=uploadImage]')[0];
```

Then you can set src of the image:

```
img.setSrc('http://www.sencha.com/img/v2/logo.png');
```

Comment: Yes, totally forgot that bit about query function. Thanks!